# Shiny apps stops working when ML libraries are imported

Tags: r, shiny

I´m working on a simple app with an ML model. The app works just fine locally but when I try to deploy it to shiny I get the following error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object.
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Ejecución interrumpida
```

[image]

I have updated OR to the latest version (5.2) and installed all packages again. But And still getting the same error.

I try then with the a simpler app and realize that the issue appears when I import either caret or iml libraries, since the icon on the top of the GUI changes and is not reconizing the code as a proper shiny app.

[image]

After importing  caret and iml

[image]

Comment: Found [this post](https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno/issues/61) with some tips. You should have a look, at least you may try if splitting in ui.R and server.R files works or not.

Comment: @alessio That worked for the libraries issue.